# closing oracle connection

Tags: .net-3.5

I have used oracle connection like below.

```
using (OracleConnection connection = OracleHelper.GetConnection(this.ConnectionStringKey))
{
  //some code
}
```

This connection needs to be closed manually or it gets closed when the function is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dispose` will be called on the connection when the block goes out of scope, so the connection will be closed automatically.

That's the whole point of having `using` statements.